# angular-cli : mousewheel directive

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a `mouseWheel` directive for my project that I'vefound **[here](https://github.com/SodhanaLibrary/angular2-examples/blob/master/app/zoomInZoomOutImage/mousewheel.directive.ts)** , but I can't get it to work.

I am trying to get a hold of those `mouseWheelUp` and `mouseWheelDown` directives so that I can control what happens on scroll up/down.

I have it imported, declared and exported in my `SharedModule` , and I have my `SharedModule` imported in my main header's module

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { LayoutService } from 'app/core/services/layout.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'header-main',
    templateUrl: 'header-main.component.html'
})

export class HeaderMainComponent {

    constructor(private layoutService: LayoutService, private renderer: Renderer) { }

    scrollUp() {
        console.log('Mouse wheel scrolled up');
    }

    scrollDown() {
        console.log('Mouse wheel scrolled down');
    }
}
```

And in my template I have:

```
<header class="header-main" (mouseWheelUp)="scrollUp()" (mouseWheelDown)="scrollDown()">
```

When I scroll down, nothing shows up in the console. What should I do to get this up to speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element doesn't match the selector of the directive.
Add `mouseWheel` anywhere in the HTML tag.

Example:

```
<header mouseWheel class="header-main" (mouseWheelUp)="scrollUp()" (mouseWheelDown)="scrollDown()">
```

Comment: Aww, yes, forgot to include the directive reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are defining selector as : header-main in your decorator , but in your HTML you are referring it as a class. Header-main should be your custom tag or if you want to use it as class or some other attribute then define it in meta-data as selector : '[header-main]'